# Access .csv file from a dll

Tags: dll, dllexport

I am trying to access a file inside my DLL, but fopen always returns NULL. I am not very familiar with DLL's and I do not know how to debug this problem. I tried to run my program with executable and it runs without an error. I am posting my .c and .h files below, any help appreciated.
ReadFile1.c:

```
#include "ReadFile1.h"
    #define MAX_STR_LEN 257
    #define MAX_Color_Maps 17
    int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall ReadF(char* ColorMap)
    {
        FILE* bookFile;
        /* allocation of the buffer for every line in the File */
        char* buf = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
        char* tmp;
        /* if the space could not be allocated, return an error */
        if (buf == NULL)
        {
            printf("No memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ((bookFile = fopen("Colormaps2.csv", "r")) == NULL) //Reading a file
        {
            printf("File could not be opened.\n");
            printf("%s",strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        struct Color_decider Colors[MAX_Color_Maps];
        int i = 1;
        fgets(buf, 256, bookFile);
        tmp = strtok(buf, ";");
        char* temp1;
        temp1= strdup(tmp);
        strncpy(Colors[0].Color_maps, temp1, strlen(temp1));
        while (i<17)
        {
            tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
            temp1 = strdup(tmp);
            strncpy(Colors[i].Color_maps, temp1, strlen(temp1));
            i++;
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < 17; k++)
{
    if (!strcmp(Colors[k].Color_maps, ColorMap))  // Find the input column.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {
            fgets(buf, 256, bookFile);
            tmp = strtok(buf, ";");
            for (int l = 1; l < k * 3; l++)
                tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");

            tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
            temp1 = strdup(tmp);
            Colors->C[j][0] = atoi(temp1);
            tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
            temp1 = strdup(tmp);
            Colors->C[j][1] = atoi(temp1);
            tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
            temp1 = strdup(tmp);
            Colors->C[j][2] = atoi(temp1);
            printf("%d\t", Colors->C[j][0]);
            printf("%d\t", Colors->C[j][1]);
            printf("%d\n", Colors->C[j][2]);

        }
        break;
    }
}
free(buf);
fclose(bookFile);
return 0;
    }
```

ReadFile1.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
struct Color_decider {
    char Color_maps[10];
    int C[256][3];
};
char *strdup(char *org)
{
    int org_size;
    static char *dup;
    char *dup_offset;
    /* Allocate memory for duplicate */
    org_size = strlen(org);
    dup = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*org_size+1);
    if( dup == NULL)
        return( (char *)NULL);

    /* Copy string */
    dup_offset = dup;
    while(*org)
    {
        *dup_offset = *org;
        dup_offset++;
        org++;
    }
    *dup_offset = '\0';

    return(dup);
}
int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall ReadF(char* ColorMap);
```

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with the *.dll*. Try specifying the full path to the file (even better: make it an argument to the function).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but I am still suffering from the same problem, although I hardcoded the path. Do you have any more suggestions?